# How to derive the following in Ho Lee Model?

Tags: integration, derivatives, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the proof of the zero bond price $Z(t)$ of the Ho-Lee model which is the unique solution of the following SDE:

$$ dZ(t) = -Z(t) [ \sigma(T-t)dW(t) + [ \int_t^T \alpha(t,u)du - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(T-t)^2]dt] \tag{1}
$$

Now using the definition of $$Z(t) := \frac{P(t,T)}{B(t)} \tag{2}$$
where $$P(t,T)= e^{-\int_t^Tf(0,s)ds - \int_0^t \int_t^T \alpha(s,u)duds - \sigma W(t)(T-t)} \tag{3}
$$
and
$$ B(t) = e^{\int_0^t f(0,s)ds +\int_0^t \int_s^t \alpha(s,u)duds + \sigma \int_0^tW(s)ds} \tag{4}
$$

I calculate $Z(t)$ as:
$$ Z(t) = P(0,T) e^{\int_0^ta(s)dW(s) -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^ta(s)^2ds + \int_0^tb(s)ds} \tag{5}
$$
where
$$ a(s) = -\sigma (T-s) \tag{6} $$
$$b(s) = \frac{1}{2}a(s)^2 +\int_s^T\alpha(s,u)du \tag{7}
$$

Now onto my question: I am trying to calculate $dZ(t)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{dZ(t)}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt} [P(0,T). e^{Y(t)}] \\
&= Z(t). dY(t) \tag{8}
\end{align}

where $Y(t)$ is the term in the exponent of (5)

However, my $\frac{dY(t)}{dt}$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{dY(t)}{dt} &= (a(t)-a(0))(W(t)-W(0)) - \frac{1}{2}(a(t)^2 - a(0)^2) +b(t)-b(0) \\
&= \sigma(t)W(t) + \int_t^T\alpha(t,u)du - \int_0^T\alpha(0,u)du \tag{9}
\end{align}

which is clearly not consistent with what I want in (1).

Can anyone help me out in determining the mistake? How should I rectify my $dY(t)/dt$ in (9)?

Comment: What is $\alpha(s,u)$ ? I have brought my $P(t,T)$ as closely as possible into the form of your equation (8) now and am expecting a response.

Comment: I used $\alpha(s,u)$ as some time-dependent drift model.

Comment: This $\alpha$ has a very specifc form in every model. See recent edit. I know now what your $P(t,T)$ is but not why you call $Z$ the zero bond and what $B$ is and why you are interested in those objects and their SDEs.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too complicated and confusing nomenclature/notation. The short rate in the Ho-Lee model is
$$\tag{1}
r_t=r_0+\Theta(t)+\sigma\,W_t\,,\quad\text{ or equivalently, }\quad dr_t=\theta(t)\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t
$$
where $\Theta(t)=\int_0^t\theta(s)\,ds\,.$

Obviously $r_0$ can be absorbed into the function $\Theta(t)$ which I will do from now on. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^t r_s\,ds&=\int_0^t\Theta(s)\,ds+\sigma\int_0^tW_s\,ds=
\int_0^t\Theta(s)\,ds+\sigma\int_0^t(t-s)\,dW_s\\
&=\int_0^t\Theta(s)\,ds+\sigma\,t\,W_t-\sigma\int_0^ts\,dW_s\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Likewise
\begin{align}
\int_t^T r_s\,ds&=
\int_t^T\Theta(s)\,ds+\sigma\,T\,W_T-\sigma\,t\,W_t-\sigma \int_t^T s\,dW_s\\
&=\int_t^T\Theta(s)\,ds+\sigma\,(T-t)W_t+\sigma \int_t^T(T-s)\,dW_s\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
The ***zero bond price*** is
\begin{align}
P(t,T)&=\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_t^T r_s\,ds\Big)\Big|{\cal F}_t\Big]\\
&=\exp\Big(-\int_t^T \Theta(s)\,ds-\sigma\,(T-t)W_t\Big)\\
&\quad\times\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_t^T (T-s)\,dW_s\Big)\Big|{\cal F}_t\Big]\\
&=\exp\Big(-\int_t^T \Theta(s)\,ds-\sigma\,(T-t)W_t+\sigma\int_0^t (T-s)\,dW_s\Big)\\
&\quad\times\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_0^T (T-s)\,dW_s\Big)\Big|{\cal F}_t\Big]\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
Let's concentrate on the conditional expectation in the last line.
From
\begin{align}\tag{5}
\Big\langle\int_0^. (T-s)\,dW_s \Big\rangle_t=\int_0^t(T-s)^2\,ds=\frac{(t-T)^3+T^3}{3}
\end{align}
it follows that
\begin{align}\tag{6}
\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_0^t(T-s)\,dW_s-\sigma^2\frac{(t-T)^3+T^3}{6}\Big)
\end{align}
is a martingale in $t\in[0,T]\,.$ Therefore,
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_0^T(T-s)\,dW_s\Big)\Big|{\cal F}_t\Big]\\
&=
\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_0^t(T-s)\,dW_s-\sigma^2\frac{(t-T)^3+T^3}{6}\Big)\exp\Big(\sigma^2\frac{T^3}{6}\Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(-\sigma\int_0^t(T-s)\,dW_s-\sigma^2\frac{(t-T)^3}{6}\Big)\,.\tag{7}
\end{align}
In total
$$\tag{8}
\boxed{\quad
P(t,T)=\exp\Big(-\int_t^T \Theta(s)\,ds-\sigma\,(T-t)W_t-\sigma^2\frac{(t-T)^3}{6}\Big)\,.
\quad}
$$
To get the SDE that this satisfies we use Ito's formula:
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
dP(t,T)&=P(t,T)\Big\{\Theta(t)+\sigma\,W_t-\cancel{\sigma^2\frac{(t-T)^2}{2}}\Big\}\,dt\\
&\quad-P(t,T)\,\sigma\,(T-t)\,dW_t+\cancel{P(t,T)\sigma^2\frac{(T-t)^2}{2}\,dt}\tag{9}
\end{align}
so that
$$\tag{10}
\boxed{\quad
\frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)}=\Big\{\Theta(t)+\sigma\,W_t\Big\}\,dt-\sigma\,(T-t)\,dW_t\,.
\quad}
$$
Note that this is equal to
$$\tag{11}
\boxed{\quad
\frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)}=r_t\,dt-\sigma\,(T-t)\,dW_t
\quad}
$$
as it should.

To find the HJM forward rates $f(t,T)$ that are related with the zero bond by
$$\tag{12}
P(t,T)=\exp\Big(-\int_t^Tf(t,s)\,ds\Big)\,,
$$
we note that from (8)
$$\tag{13}
f(t,T)=-\frac{d}{dT}\log P(t,T)=\Theta(T)+\sigma\,W_t-\sigma^2\frac{(T-t)^2}{2}\,.
$$
As expected, $f(t,t)=r_t$ and
$$\tag{14}
f(0,T)=\Theta(T)-\sigma^2\frac{T^2}{2}\,.
$$
Since
\begin{align}\tag{15}
f(t,T)&=f(0,T)+\sigma^2\frac{T^2}{2}-\sigma^2\frac{(T-t)^2}{2}+\sigma\,W_t
\end{align}
the equations (8) and (12) can also be written as
$$\tag{16}
P(t,T)
=\exp\Big(-\int_t^Tf(0,s)\,ds-\sigma\,(T-t)\,W_t-\sigma^2\frac{T^3-t^3-(T-t)^3}{6}\Big)\,.
$$
A final remark on the drift of the forward rate $f(t,T)\,$: from HJM we know that this must be of the form
$$\tag{17}
\alpha(t,T)=\sigma(t,T)\int_t^T\sigma(t,s)\,ds
$$
where $\sigma(t,T)$ is $f$'s volatility function. In the Ho-Lee model
this is constant, $\sigma(t,T)=\sigma\,,$ so that
$$\tag{18}
\alpha(t,T)=\sigma^2\,(T-t)\,.
$$
Then, from $\int_0^t\alpha(u,T)\,du=\sigma^2\frac{T^2-(T-t)^2}{2}\,$, we see that
(15) can be written in the familiar HJM form
$$\tag{19}
f(t,T)=f(0,T)+\int_0^t\alpha(s,T)\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s,T)\,dW_s\,.
$$
With the Ho-Lee $\alpha(t,T)$ from (18) we can also write (16) as
$$\tag{20}
\boxed{\,
P(t,T)
=\exp\Big(-\int_t^Tf(0,s)\,ds-\sigma\,(T-t)\,W_t-\int_t^T
\int_0^t\alpha(u,s)\,du\,ds\Big)\,.
\,}
$$